# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished for new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a wrong choice and now I am sticked at the middle of my project
I used ruby 5.0.0rc1, and while I start my project with rubymine I get "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished"

I also get an error message while I type rake db:create :

```
Gregoires-MacBook-Pro:p1 gregoire$ rake db:create
Rake tasks not supported by 'pg' adapter
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"pg", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"pg"}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseNotSupported: Rake tasks not supported by 'pg' adapter
```

---

my database/yml :

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: 'pg'
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: 'pg'

test:
  <<: *default
  database: 'pg'

production:
  <<: *default
  database: 'pg'
```

I am newbie with ror , any help will be appreciated (please detail)

greg

Comment: You mean `rails 5.0.0rc1`? :)

Comment: Think the adapter should be `adapter: sqlite3` if you are using sqlite3

Comment: Need more information. Are you trying to use postgresql or sqlite ? For clarity reasons I would give the database a different name than the adapter. If you're using postgres you need to give rails a username and password. If you're using sqlite you need to change the 'adapter'.

Comment: yes, rails 5.0.0rc1, not a good idea for a beginner

Comment: I wanted to user postgres, the templating of my editor (RubyMine) created using  adapter: pg, I took commented next template and It works better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config/database.yml` gives Rails the information needed to access the database of your choice.

The adapter name `pg` is not valid. If you intend to use PostgreSQL, you should set it as `postgresql`.

And you have to make sure [PostgreSQL is installed and running](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#set-up-postgres-on-mac).

A typical `database.yml` could be like the following:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: your_username_for_postgresql
  password: your_password_for_postgresql

development:
  <<: *default
  database: your_app_name_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: your_app_name_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: your_app_name_production
  username: your_username_for_postgresql_on_production
  password: your_password_for_postgresql_on_production
```

Comment: thanks, I cut & past your configuration and I changed some parameters but it gave me the result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I had multiple problems :

1/ Postgresql was not properly installed AND running
   Fresh install using some comments found here :
   https://gist.github.com/lxneng/741932

2/ my database .yml was nos properly configured, I created users with 
   new access : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/

What you gave me as advise made me find the way, also a project 'out of the box' was not runable

Thanks for your time and advises

greg